# How to set record choice to show options in ascending sort order in new “Flow Builder”?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created a Record Choice from a custom metadata object that stores countries. The custom metadata label is the country's name. Here's my Record Choice configuration:

[image]

However, when I run the Flow, the list is not sorted:

[image]

I checked the Flow XML and it does show the proper sort order.

What more do I need to do to sort the list?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this exact same problem. Realizing this post is over 1 year old but maybe someone else will find value in the answer. The solution was to include the sort order field as one of the stored variables (even though I am not using it at all) and then the record choice set was sorted as expected.

So in your record choice set within the flow, under "Store More Field Values" section, just add the field you want to sort by, store it in a variable even though you may not use it at all, and it should work.

In my example below, I'm building a record choice set out of a custom metadata type called "Service Queues" and I want to sort them in ascending order of a field on that object called "Sort Order". Until I added the sort order field to the bottom section, it did not sort on that field.

[image: Screenshot from Flow Builder]